React Js unable to detect update in object
I have Dynamically generate select dropdown & I'm seting the value of drop down from key of a object when I select value from a drop down I update my object and object succesfully updated but my drop down doest not show the updated value in UI.
  const [mappingArr,setMappingArr] = useState({});

  const mapping = async (tableFields, excel) => {
    const newRows = excel.map((colName, index) => {
      mappingArr[colName] = 'name'
      setMappingArr(mappingArr)
      return {
        "column name": colName,
        "Map to field": (
          <select
            value={mappingArr[colName]}
            key = {tableFields[index]}
            onChange={(event) => { handleSelectColumn(event, colName, index)}}
          >
            <option value=''>--Select--</option>
            {tableFields.map((col,i) => (
              <option key={col} value={col}>
                {col}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        ),
      }
    });
    setRow(newRows);
  };

  const handleSelectColumn = async (event, colName, index) => {
    mappingArr[colName] = event.target.value
   setMappingArr(mappingArr)
   };

I tried not setting the value at all so that drop down behaves like a native element but in that case when I scroll down the page component re-renders my html element(drop down) & forgets its selected value, hence setting the value is required here.

You need to create a separate component for the dropdown and so that every instance of the dropdown has a separate state

I have made seperate new component for select but still my drop down box doest not show selected value .
function SelectBox({options, onChange }) {
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('');
const handleChange = (event) => {const value =event.target.value;setSelectedValue(value);onChange(value);
};
return (

--Select--
{options.map((option) => (
{option}
))}

)
}
export default SelectBox;

Can you update your  question with the updated code now.
Also paste the excel and tableFields data or data structure
